# How to add uitabbarcontroller to uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a view based application in which in the first view i dont want tabbar controller and from the views other than that (that is from 2 nd view ..)i want to have tabbar controller .
I googled it but couldnt get a solution .

Comment: Hello,I am having the same issue.Can u please help me how u had solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with view based application. And then create a UITabbarController in you appDelegate file.

Appdelegate.h

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties

Appdelegate.m

// Synthsize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

//Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

You can accordingly manage in which tab you want to place navigation controller or only a view controller.

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.

Comment: Hello,By [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];  it will add the tabbar from firstview.But i want to add the tab bar fro 2nd view controller.Please help me.